# How to get id from php using datatable in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, datatable

I dont know how to get id from php in datatable. I try create new variable but it won't work

```
var table = $('#table-show').DataTable({
            "scrollX": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":  "person_search.php",
            order: [[2, 'asc']],
            columnDefs: [{

                orderable: false,
                defaultContent:'<a href="person_form.php?id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'&action=edit" class="mr-3"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>'
                +
                '  <a href="person_form.php?id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'&action=delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>',
                targets: -1
             }]
        });
```

Comment: What is `$row`?

Comment: it is from my php file, to get the id for edit or delete

Comment: this approach won't work since the script is being written once in the back-end and delivered to the front where columnDefs is applied per each row but with the same $row['id'] that was written in the back-end (if at all). i think you should use another approach, while writing the table itself (with all the data), and attach the desired id in there

Comment: you can pass the id in your json data and use render callback in that column to display anchor tag with id passed in your desired attribute